# SSIS - matching rows from the input file to similar rows in input which differ only by one column value

Tags: ssis

I have an input file that has 5 columns.

```
Portfolio
Currency
Security Name
Date
Balance
```

I am using an SSIS package in SQL Server 2008 to read through this input file and save it to the database.

I am giving a sample input as follows:

```
ABC,EUR,HIJKLMNO,2017-05-01,1200.00 
ABC,USD,HIJKLMNO,2017-05-01,1300.00 
DEF,EUR,ABCDEFG,2017-05-01,1100.00 
DEF,GBP,ABCDEFG,2017-05-01,1500.00
```

I am looking for an output as follows:

```
ABC,EURUSD,HIJKLMNO,2017-05-01,1200.00,1300.00
DEF,EURGBP,ABCDEFG,2017-05-01,1100.00,1500.00
```

So in effect, I am combining the two currency entries into one line for the same portfolio. In the output, I am just concatenating the two currencies in the second column and also I am adding the second currency amount as a new column in the result. Would this be possible through SSIS?

Comment: You can use DERIVED Column for this purpose. This might help you: http://www.tutorialgateway.org/derived-column-transformation-in-ssis/

Comment: Because you want every 2 of your rows to become 1, and Balance to become 2 columns, you will need to pivot.
This can be achieved either in the SQL query of your source itself with PIVOT operator:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx,
or in SSIS with Pivot Transformation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/pivot-transformation